# XSLT 1.0 Help in Sorting

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a requirement where i need to do sorting and grouping. I have worked my XSLT with sorting but its not giving me the desired output ,

Input XML :

```
<ns0:Root xmlns:ns0="http://TestXSLT1._0.Output">
  <SeqNo>1</SeqNo>
  <FileName>Test</FileName>
  <DestinationLocation>Miami</DestinationLocation>
  <DestinationName>State</DestinationName>
  <Detail>
    <ItemName>Item1</ItemName>
    <Rate>100</Rate>
  </Detail>
  <Detail>
    <ItemName>Item2</ItemName>
    <Rate>200</Rate>
  </Detail>
  <Detail>
    <ItemName>Item3</ItemName>
    <Rate>300</Rate>
  </Detail>
  <Detail>
    <ItemName>Item1</ItemName>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
  </Detail>
  <Detail>
    <ItemName>Item2</ItemName>
    <Quantity>2</Quantity>
  </Detail>
</ns0:Root>
```

Desired OutPut :

```
<ns0:Root xmlns:ns0="http://TestXSLT1._0.Output">
        <SeqNo>1</SeqNo>
        <FileName>Test</FileName>
        <DestinationLocation>Miami</DestinationLocation>
        <DestinationName>State</DestinationName>
        <Detail>
            <ItemName>Item1</ItemName>
            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
            <Rate>100</Rate>
        </Detail>
        <Detail>
            <ItemName>Item2</ItemName>
            <Quantity>2</Quantity>
            <Rate>200</Rate>
        </Detail>
        <Detail>
            <ItemName>Item3</ItemName>
            <Rate>3</Rate>
        </Detail>
    </ns0:Root>
```

XSLT :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="detail-by-item" match="Detail" use="ItemName"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="*[not(self::Detail)]"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="Detail[generate-id()=generate-id(key('detail-by-item', ItemName))]">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:copy-of select="ItemName"/>
          <xsl:copy-of select="key('detail-by-item', ItemName)/*[not(self::ItemName)]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Issue :

So the XSLT is grouping and Copying but the xml is not validating with xsd as Detail hierarchy is wrong.It Should Be ItemName,Quantity,Rate.

Appreciate the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="detail-by-item" match="Detail" use="ItemName"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*[not(self::Detail)]"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="Detail[generate-id()=generate-id(key('detail-by-item', ItemName))]">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="ItemName"/>
                <xsl:variable name="grp" select="key('detail-by-item', ItemName)" />
                <xsl:copy-of select="$grp/Quantity"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="$grp/Rate"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```